# Get selected select option form database that have multiple select value Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

This is my table, u can see from my table below that in 1 `column` we can input 2 `values`, my question is how to get that value and put it into the right `select option`

```
 No  |  Course_Code  | Course_Score |
  1  |  CC001,CC002  |     A, B     |
  2  |  CC003,       |     C,       |
```

here are my select option, u can see i have 4 different selects or u called it dropdown, and when i click **edit** button i want to put the first `course_code` into the correct `course_code` select and put the `course_score` into the right course score, how can i do that?

[image]

this it how i put 2 value in my table and my function to get the `Course`

```
public function save(id=null){
    'Course_code'=>$this->input->post("course_code1").', '.$this->input->post("course_code2"),
    'Course_Score'=>$this->input->post("course_score1").', '.$this->input->post("course_score2")
}
public function combo_course(){
    //GET ALL COURSE LIST
    $kodePro = $this->input->post('pro_id');//09
    $matkulCombo = $this->cms_matakuliah_m->getMatkul($this->session->userdata('kodePS'))->result();
    $list_combo = "";
    $list_combo .= "<option value='0'>Choose</option>";
    foreach($matkulCombo as $rows):
        $list_combo .="<option value='".$rows->Course_code."'>".$rows->Course_name."</option>";
    endforeach;
    echo $list_combo;
}
```

this is my view

```
<select  id="courseCode" class="form-control">
//I use AJAX to get the Course
</select>
<select disabled id="cScore" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Choose</option>
   <option value="A" <?php if(isset($matkul->Course_Score)) echo ($matkul->Course_Score == 1)?"selected":"" ?>>A</option>
   <option value="B" <?php if(isset($matkul->Course_Score)) echo ($matkul->Course_Score == 2)?"selected":"" ?>>B</option>
   <option value="C" <?php if(isset($matkul->Course_Score)) echo ($matkul->Course_Score == 3)?"selected":"" ?>>C</option>
   <option value="D" <?php if(isset($matkul->Course_Score)) echo ($matkul->Course_Score == 4)?"selected":"" ?>>D</option>
   <option value="E" <?php if(isset($matkul->Course_Score)) echo ($matkul->Course_Score == 5)?"selected":"" ?>>E</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

use form helper then pass the default value

```
echo form_dropdown('course_code1', $get_matkul, $currentValue, "id='courseCode' class='input-large'");
```

- 1st parameter is the name of the element
- 2nd are the options
- 3rd is the selected value
- 4th are the attributes

Comment: This time i can't use ur way, because i work on some project, so i need to adjust when other programmer style of code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
//    $get_matkul is course codes from database table. right?
$get_scores = mysqli_fetch_array($result);//(a,b,c,d,...) from table
$Course_codes = explode(',',$matkul->Course_code);
$Course_Scores = explode(',',$matkul->Course_Score);?>
<select  id="courseCode" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <?php foreach($get_matkul as $rows): 
        $selected = "";
        foreach($Course_codes as $Course_code){
            if($Course_code == $rows->Course_code){
                $selected = "Selected";
            }
        }?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rows->Course_code?>" <?php echo $selected;?> >
        <?php echo $rows->Course_name ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<select disabled id="cScore" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <?php foreach($get_scores as $score): 
        $selected = "";
        foreach($Course_Scores as $Course_Score){
            if($Course_Score == $score->Course_Score){
                $selected = "Selected";
            }
        }?>
    <option value="<?php echo $score->Course_Score;?>" <?php echo $selected ?>><?php echo $score->Course_Score;?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: sorry i just work on another project, ur code give an same output to 2 of the select option, so it didn't work, maybe u can take a look at my question again i make an adjustment

Comment: ah yes and btw my `course score`(A,B,C,D,E) dropdown is not from database, but manually populated

Comment: @romaltandel, I have on the query, what if we have only one dropdown instated of four?

Comment: @user9437856 its general code to get selected value.